# Multiprocessing a python function that contains a for loop

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

So I have a script that converts XML files to CSV, this script has a function that contains nested loops, juste 2 loop to be precise :

```
FichList = [ f for f in os.listdir(FilenamePath) ]

def SplitFichierR50 (l_FichList):
    for filename in FichList:
            if filename.count(".xml") ==1: 
                    print(filename)
                    tree = etree.parse(FilenamePath+"/"+filename)
                    for mes in tree.xpath("/R50/PRM/Donnees_Releve"):
                            l_ID_PRM =mes.getparent()[0]
                            EN_TETE=mes.getparent().getparent()[0]
                            l_ID_FLUX = EN_TETE[0]
                            l_LIB_FLUX = EN_TETE[1]
                            .
                            .
                            .
```

Etc... until having all the XML data and writing it in the CSV file, this script works fine, but I have to optimize the execution of it to make it work faster, so I used the multiprocessing module adding this to the script :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  jobs = []
  for i in range(10): # I want to use 10 CPUs
  p = multiprocessing.Process(target=SplitFichierR50,args=(FichList,))
  jobs.append(p)
  p.start()
```

It does execute the script on 10 CPUs but it does the same thing 10 times for the same file.
[image]

Here in the screenshot I used just 3 CPU but we can see that it's the same file 3 times.

I want to execute each iteraion of the loop on a different CPU.

Please help !!

Comment: Please fix indentation.

Comment: @ikac what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is hard for me to independently test but it appears that you have a bug. First off, your `SplitFichierR50` function takes in a list `l_FichList` but it isn't used in the function. In fact, every single one of the processes is simply going to go through every file in `FichList`. That is why you are seeing so many duplicate file processing messages. You need to partition out the filenames in `FichList` so that each process is handling a different set of files.

For example, something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    num_processes = 10
    step = int(math.ceil(float(len(FichList))/float(num_processes)))
    for i in range(0, len(FichList), step):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=SplitFichierR50,args=(FichList[i:i+step],))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Make sure to `import math` and to correct the `SplitFichierR50` function to use the passed in list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the result did not change, I still the same line 10 times.